# Google lock port that was previously enabled

Tags: server, port, google-compute-engine, telnet

I have an instance in google cloud. Within this instance I have a mail service that leaves through port 8025. It works for 5 months however, yesterday I stopped having access to that port.

How can I solve it?
Thank you

[image]

Comment: About using "urgent" and similar phrases on Stack Overflow: [check here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest#answer-326590).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check the firewall rules of your project at `VCP network > Firewall Rules` and see if you have a firewall rule for port 8025.

You can create a new firewall rule using the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)

Comment: Thank you bit ejem i Saw the firewall rule i see the port 8025 is enable to out and in tráfico

Comment: Maybe you can try using port 465, 587 or an third-party service to send the emails per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/)

Comment: Thank you but Google block this ports